# Simple program using JOptionPane to navigate options continues to rewrite ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, joptionpane

I've defined the ArrayList qList in my constructor as

```
ArrayList<Question> qList = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

Followed by a while loop that allows you to navigate some Jpanes t

```
while(!menuDialog.toLowerCase().equals("end"))
    {
        if(menuDialog.toLowerCase().equals("a"))
        {
            ques = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your question now.");
            ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your answer now.");
            Question q = new Question(ques, ans);
            qList.add(q);
            System.out.println(qList.size());
        }
        else if(menuDialog.toLowerCase().equals("b"))
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < qList.size(); i++)
            {
                System.out.println(qList.get(i).getQuestion() + "\t" + qList.get(i).getAnswer());
            }
            menuDialog = "end";
        }
    else if(menuDialog.toLowerCase().equals("c"))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            String error = new String();
            error = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Incorrect input, please enter a proper variable.");
            menuDialog = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(menu);
        }
}
```

When I press "A" to be directed to where I can add a question, I am given the correct prompts. Then I add whatever input, and it takes me back to menuDialog, where I then enter "B". This should end the loop and present the list in the console, which it isn't.

I also added the size check in A, which proves that it gets rewritten because it only ever prints "1".

Have I done something particularly stupid?

Comment: You've told us what you **wanted** to happen (which didn't happen).  So tell us what actually **did** happen instead (that you _didn't_ want)?

Comment: ...`cuz just looking at the code, it seems to me like it _ought_ to be working the way you wanted.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).